# Visual Studio 2013 gives error message when try to save

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013. A couple of days ago, my computer shutted down accidentally after that I always get error when I try to save my visual studio files.It saves but it gives error message.

[image: Here the screenshot.]

The log file is

```
27.5.2016 09:47:43
Recoverable
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Assumes+InternalErrorException: An internal error occurred. Please contact Microsoft Product Support Services.
   at Microsoft.Assumes.Fail(String message, Boolean showAssert)
   at Microsoft.Assumes.NotNull[T](T value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectDirectoryTreeProvider.<ProcessFileEventsAddFileAsync>d__5c.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectDirectoryTreeProvider.<ProcessFileEventsAsync>d__4c.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Utilities.Designers.ProjectTreeProviderBase.<>c__DisplayClass9.<<Initialize>b__5>d__b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Utilities.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectErrorReporting.<>c__DisplayClass5.<SubmitErrorReport>b__3()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ExceptionFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Guard>b__0()
   at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(Func`1 , Func`2 , Func`2 )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.Assumes+InternalErrorException: An internal error occurred. Please contact Microsoft Product Support Services.
   at Microsoft.Assumes.Fail(String message, Boolean showAssert)
   at Microsoft.Assumes.NotNull[T](T value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectDirectoryTreeProvider.<ProcessFileEventsAddFileAsync>d__5c.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectDirectoryTreeProvider.<ProcessFileEventsAsync>d__4c.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Utilities.Designers.ProjectTreeProviderBase.<>c__DisplayClass9.<<Initialize>b__5>d__b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Utilities.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectErrorReporting.<>c__DisplayClass5.<SubmitErrorReport>b__3()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ExceptionFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Guard>b__0()
   at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(Func`1 , Func`2 , Func`2 )<---

===================
27.5.2016 10:00:24
Recoverable
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Assumes+InternalErrorException: An internal error occurred. Please contact Microsoft Product Support Services.
   at Microsoft.Assumes.Fail(String message, Boolean showAssert)
   at Microsoft.Assumes.NotNull[T](T value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectDirectoryTreeProvider.<ProcessFileEventsAddFileAsync>d__5c.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectDirectoryTreeProvider.<ProcessFileEventsAsync>d__4c.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Utilities.Designers.ProjectTreeProviderBase.<>c__DisplayClass9.<<Initialize>b__5>d__b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Utilities.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectErrorReporting.<>c__DisplayClass5.<SubmitErrorReport>b__3()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ExceptionFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Guard>b__0()
   at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(Func`1 , Func`2 , Func`2 )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.Assumes+InternalErrorException: An internal error occurred. Please contact Microsoft Product Support Services.
   at Microsoft.Assumes.Fail(String message, Boolean showAssert)
   at Microsoft.Assumes.NotNull[T](T value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectDirectoryTreeProvider.<ProcessFileEventsAddFileAsync>d__5c.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Designers.ProjectDirectoryTreeProvider.<ProcessFileEventsAsync>d__4c.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Utilities.Designers.ProjectTreeProviderBase.<>c__DisplayClass9.<<Initialize>b__5>d__b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Utilities.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectErrorReporting.<>c__DisplayClass5.<SubmitErrorReport>b__3()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ExceptionFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Guard>b__0()
   at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(Func`1 , Func`2 , Func`2 )
 <---

===================
```

I wonder if there is any solution.
Thank you

Comment: can you share some project configuration as well?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for Microsoft PSS; and probably a re-install will fix it anyway.

Comment: Sure, but I am a new user in Visual Studio .Can you explain which configuration file is useful for you ?

Comment: Is it a large project?  Should you recreate the project / Solution?  Do you have it under source control and therefore can revert to a previously working version?